# Is it possible to have the translation-system and use-system on two different machines?

Tags: python, translation, gettext

I have two system:

**System A:**
This will show translated system with ugettext from mo-files.

**System B:**
This will handle the po-files and translate the content.

The two system are on different machines, but on the same servernode.

The mo-translations are cached up so after read they will not be requested again.

*I'm looking for a good solution on how I can solve this.*

**Update:**

I need a good way to get these two system to work together.

Comment: Ok? What do you need solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create an API (via JSON-RPC, XML-RPC, SOAP, CORBA, DCOM, smoke signals, string and tin cans, *it doesn't fricking matter...*) that allows the client to specify the original string, language, count, and context, and have the server perform the translation and return the translated string.

If the translation API reflects the gettext API then it could be used as a drop-in replacement for the gettext module and the client would not require any recoding except possibly to specify the server.

Comment: This is something I had in mind, but sending binary data over http.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just host the po-files on a shared drive and check for updates to the files.

Comment: Through what protocol would you suggest this is done?

Comment: They do, but I need to move the files in some way.

Comment: If it's a shared drive, then you don't need to move the file, no?

Comment: That's true, but this needs to mobile since there is no garantuee on where a drive is located. In theory one of the machines could be located on another server node in the future.